# Thymelaf Spring forms with checkboxes generate noisy urls due to hidden inputs

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Thymeleaf Spring creates hidden inputs when using forms with checkboxes, as per http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Thymeleaf-Spring3.html#checkbox-fields

The generated url when submitting the form as a GET method has a lot of noise:

```
/search?q=stuff&_filters=on&filters=Foo&_filters=on&filters=Bar&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on&_filters=on
```

The url I want see is

```
/search?q=stuff&filters=Foo&filters=Bar
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get this to work with a javascript hack that intercepts the form submission and removes all the hidden '_filters' inputs:

```
function interceptFilterForm(form){
    var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
        var input = inputs[i];
        if (input.type == "hidden" && input.name == "_filters") {
            input.parentNode.removeChild(input);
        }
    }

    form.submit();
}
```

The form:

```
<form th:action="@{/search}" method="GET" th:object="${searchForm}" onsubmit="interceptFilterForm(this);">
  <input type="hidden" name="q" th:value="${searchForm.q}" />
  <input type="submit" value="Filter" ></input>

  <li th:each="facet : ${results.facets}" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="filters" th:value="${facet.fullPath}" th:field="*{filters}" />
  </li>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a post-request. The problem is that you need the information for the binding, otherwise you can't know if the checkbox was unchecked or not shown.